# terraform provisioner - local exec bin/sh Directory nonexistent error

Tags: ssl, terraform, exec, bin

Using terraform to create some self signed tlf certs for hashi vault, the main problematic terraform bits in my module is as follows, I have tried 2 ways to get this to work.

First way, which in theory, I think should work:

```
      provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo '${self.cert_pem}' > ../tls/ca.pem && chmod 0600 ../tls/ca.pem"
  }
}

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo '${self.cert_pem}' > ../tls/vault.pem && echo '${tls_self_signed_cert.vault-ca.cert_pem}' >> ../tls/vault.pem && chmod 0600 ../tls/vault.pem"
  }
```

Which throws this error:

```
│ ' > ../tls/ca.pem && chmod 0600 ../tls/ca.pem': exit status 2. Output:
│ /bin/sh: 1: cannot create ../tls/ca.pem: Directory nonexistent
```

And if I replace the .. with a hardcoded path i.e. this:

```
      provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo '${self.cert_pem}' > /etc/vault/tls/ca.pem && chmod 0600 /etc/vault/tls/ca.pem"
  }
}

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "echo '${self.cert_pem}' > /etc/vault/tls/vault.pem && echo '${tls_self_signed_cert.vault-ca.cert_pem}' >> /etc/vault/tls/vault.pem && chmod 0600 /etc/vault/tls/vault.pem"
  }
```

I get the same error but obviously showing the path instead:

```
> /etc/vault/tls/ca.pem && chmod 0600 /etc/vault/tls/ca.pem': exit status
│ 2. Output: /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /etc/vault/tls/ca.pem: Directory
│ nonexistent
```

If I go on and look at the container for myself, the path /etc/vault/tls is there....

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that `/etc/vault/tls/` exists before you can write a file into it:

```
 provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sudo mkdir -p /etc/vault/tls && sudo echo '${self.cert_pem}' > /etc/vault/tls/ca.pem && sudo chmod 0600 /etc/vault/tls/ca.pem"
  }
```

Comment: thanks, I'm now getting permission denied when trying to create that, I did add sudo to the start of those commands but still permission denied.

Comment: It's a bad idea to install something on the machine running terraform with terraform!
BTW, can you share the command you constructed with `sudo`?

Comment: Ah ok, I'm just following an example for deploying hashi vault to GKE and part of it does the self signed tls cert, here - https://github.com/agates4/vault-on-gke/blob/master/terraform/tls.tf EDIT: Also, this is running on azure devops ci/cd pipeline so just realised, I'll need to do a copy job instead i.e.  move files from the build agent... will redo it now and report back

Comment: command I changed it to is - "provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "sudo mkdir -p /etc/vault/tls && echo '${self.cert_pem}' > /etc/vault/tls/ca.pem && chmod 0600 /etc/vault/tls/ca.pem"
  }

Comment: That's the problem with the command, you have to append `sudo` on each command after ampersand, `sudo mkdir -p /etc/vault/tls && echo "${self.cert_pem}" | sudo tee /etc/vault/tls/ca.pem && sudo chmod 0600 /etc/vault/tls/ca.pem`

Comment: thanks for the advice harshavmb & Marcin, I was able to somewhat work around it by just pointing it to the /tmp/ directory (didn't need sudo either). I think I am asking the wrong question though, seems I need figure out a way to copy the ca.pem and vault.pem over to the pod from the build agent, so probably need an additional provisioner to do a copy job.